# PCA Bounding box PCL

Tags: c++, pca, point-cloud-library

I have a problem where I have a 3D cloud in PCL `pcl::PointXYZI` and want to obtain the PCA boxes. There are some implementations being explained in other post but in my case the difference is that I just care about the orientation in the XY plane, without considering the Z axis rotation. My problem at hand is a car driving inside the city and right now I am getting this:
[image]
For a driving problem I just want to consider the orientation of an obstacle as seen from a bird's view so it does not make sense to have tilted obstacles.
My current implementation is: (from http://codextechnicanum.blogspot.com/2015/04/find-minimum-oriented-bounding-box-of.html)

```
template<typename PointT>
BoxQ ProcessPointClouds<PointT>::BoundingBoxQ(typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cluster)
{
    // Find bounding box for one of the clusters
    BoxQ box;
    Eigen::Vector4f pcaCentroid;
    pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cluster, pcaCentroid);
    Eigen::Matrix3f covariance;
    computeCovarianceMatrixNormalized(*cluster, pcaCentroid, covariance);
    Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> eigen_solver(covariance, Eigen::ComputeEigenvectors);
    Eigen::Matrix3f eigenVectorsPCA = eigen_solver.eigenvectors();
    eigenVectorsPCA.col(2) = eigenVectorsPCA.col(0).cross(eigenVectorsPCA.col(1));

    Eigen::Matrix4f projectionTransform(Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity());
    projectionTransform.block<3,3>(0,0) = eigenVectorsPCA.transpose();
    projectionTransform.block<3,1>(0,3) = -1.f * (projectionTransform.block<3,3>(0,0) * pcaCentroid.head<3>());
    typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloudPointsProjected (new pcl::PointCloud<PointT>);
    pcl::transformPointCloud(*cluster, *cloudPointsProjected, projectionTransform);
    // Get the minimum and maximum points of the transformed cloud.
    PointT minPoint, maxPoint;
    pcl::getMinMax3D(*cloudPointsProjected, minPoint, maxPoint);
    const Eigen::Vector3f meanDiagonal = 0.5f*(maxPoint.getVector3fMap() + minPoint.getVector3fMap());
    // Final transform
    box.bboxQuaternion =  eigenVectorsPCA; //Quaternions are a way to do rotations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHVwd8gYLnI
    box.bboxTransform = eigenVectorsPCA * meanDiagonal + pcaCentroid.head<3>();
    box.cube_length = std::abs(maxPoint.x-minPoint.x);
    box.cube_width = std::abs(maxPoint.y-minPoint.y);
    box.cube_height = std::abs(maxPoint.z-minPoint.z);
    return box;
}
```

I guess the problem comes during last lines where I assign min and max points but I cannot see how to remove the tilt in the object.

Answer (score 0):

For a birds-eye-view result, you can consider a 2D bounding box using the x,y coordinates from the min and max points.

This assumes your coordinate system uses the z-axis perpendicular to the ground plane.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).